# Httpd port not available from outside

Tags: centos, webserver

I found out port 7080 of my local Linux server isn't accessible externally but locally it is.

Any tips about how to resolved it?

Comment: External to what?

Comment: What is listening on it? It might be configured to just listen on a certain interface.

Comment: Firewall might need a rule to allow the traffic even if it is listening on the proper interface

Answer (score 0):

To start you can check that the firewall is allowing outbound traffic on that port with `firewall-cmd --list-rules`. Look for `ports`. If it is not listed you can open that port with:

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=7080/tcp   # if you need TCP, this is most likely
firewall-cmd --add-port=7080/udp   # if you need UDP
firewall-cmd --reload
```

To make these changes permanent add `--permanent` to the `--add-port` commands.